# How to make where condition always be true with field =?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql statement follow:

`select * from table where id = ?`

Now, problem is, l don't know whether front end will send me the value of id, if it did, this sql seem like `id = 1`, and if not, sql should be like `id = true`(fake code) to find all data

How could I write my sql?

Or, It is fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally handled by using logic such as this:

```
select *
from table
where id = ? or ? is null;
```

If you don't want to pass the parameter twice or use named parameters:

```
select t.*
from table t cross join
     (select ? as param) params
where id = params.param or params.param is null;
```

If you want to return all ids if the passed-in value does not exist:

```
select t.*
from table t
where id = ? or 
      not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = ?);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try doing is in your code, write a function for fetching a specific record, and another function for fetching all the records from your table.

In PHP, it  could be something like:

```
// Fetching a specific record
function getCustomerRecord($customerId) {
     // Code to fetch specific record from database
}


// Fetching all records
function getAllCustomerRecords() {
     // Code to fetch all records from database
}
```

In the function where you process requests received, check first if a value for id was passed. If a value for id was passed, call the function to fetch a specific record, making sure to pass along the value you received as an argument. Otherwise, call the function to fetch all the records from your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this to get your right sql statement in PHP

```
 function GetSqlStatement($id){
       return $sql = "select * from table where id = ".$id.";";
 }
```